# How can I Call a function within a function using action script 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, adobe, flex3

**How can i call function in another function using action script 3.0
Here I am Using WSDL Web service and getting data in my data grid. i want to put this data into my database table.**

I am calling Following function on Button click event which is associated to WebService .

```
private function Login():void {
                // Get Data from WebService and fill datagrid when you fist invoke the application
                SignIn1Result2.token = vtrServices.SignIn1(txtUserName.text, txtPassword.text);
                stmt.sqlConnection = this.isDbConnected(conn);
                func:addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN,insertContact);

                 /* insertContact(SignIn1Result2.lastResult.UserId,SignIn1Result2.lastResult.UserName,SignIn1Result2.lastResult.ContactName,SignIn1Result2.lastResult.Password,SignIn1Result2.lastResult.Salt); */
                }
```

**And my WebService Definition is**

```
  <fx:Declarations>
            <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
            <mx:WebService 
                id="ws" 
                wsdl="http://localhost:2690/vtrServices.asmx?wsdl"> 
                <mx:operation 
                    name="GetEmployees" 
                    resultFormat="object"
                    result="Login()"
                    />

            </mx:WebService>
            <vtrservices:VtrServices id="vtrServices"
                                     fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                     showBusyCursor="true"/>
            <s:CallResponder id="SignIn1Result2"/>
 </fx:Declarations>
```

My controls

```
<mx:Panel x="41.5" y="66" width="714.5" height="237" layout="absolute" title="ASP.NET WebService + Flex Demonstration">
        <mx:HBox height="95%" width="95%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
            <mx:DataGrid id="datagrid" width="499" height="100%"
                         dataProvider="{SignIn1Result2.lastResult}">
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="User Id" dataField="UserId"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="UserName" dataField="UserName"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="ContactName" dataField="ContactName"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Password" dataField="Password"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Salt" dataField="Salt"/>
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>

            <mx:Form x="608" y="74" width="100%" height="100%" borderStyle="solid" id="UserLogin">

                <mx:FormItem label="UserName">
                    <mx:TextInput width="106" id="txtUserName"/>
                </mx:FormItem>

                <mx:FormItem label="Password">
                    <mx:TextInput width="106" 
                                  displayAsPassword="true"
                                  id="txtPassword"/>
                </mx:FormItem>

                <mx:FormItem width="156" horizontalAlign="right">
                    <mx:Button label="Login" id="btnLogin" click="Login();"/>
                </mx:FormItem>

            </mx:Form>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Panel>
```

**here is the following function which should be called after success of Login() funtion or i can say within the Login() Function**

```
private function insertContact(UserId:String, UserName:String,ContactName:String, Password:String, Salt:String):void
            {
                stmt.sqlConnection = this.isDbConnected(conn);
                stmt.text = "INSERT INTO TblUsers (UserId, UserName, ContactName ,Password, Salt) VALUES('"+SignIn1Result2.lastResult.UserId+"','"+SignIn1Result2.lastResult.UserName+"','"+SignIn1Result2.lastResult.ContactName+"','"+SignIn1Result2.lastResult.Password+"','"+SignIn1Result2.lastResult.Salt+"');";  
                Alert.show("Contact Has been Saved");
                stmt.execute();
            }
```

I have Binded the following

```
[Bindable]
        public var conn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();


        [Bindable]
        private var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();

        // ArrayCollection used as a data provider for the datagrid. It has to be bindable so that data in datagrid changes automatically when we change the ArrayCollection

        [Bindable]
        private var contactList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

**InsertContact() Is the function that i want to call within the Login() function execution success**

Answer (score 0):

**Functions are Called within a function Just like other Scripting Languages But Here You have to Watch Carefully on what Event you want to call them.

I got It , I found the Mistakes i was doing . 
As i said i Want to call the function on Success of WebService Function 
Here the function Should be called on Result Event of The webService Call . 
So i Have just Added the Result Event to my WebService Block Of Flex Application and changed the Webservice Definition According to it**

```
<mx:WebService 
            id="ws" 
            wsdl="http://localhost:2690/vtrServices.asmx?wsdl"> 

        </mx:WebService>
        <vtrservices:VtrServices id="vtrServices"
                                 fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                 showBusyCursor="true"
                                 result="vtrServices_resultHandler(event)"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="SignIn1Result2"/>
```

Then I have used The Data Provider And its 'LastResult' Property In the **Result Event**
and the function that i want to be executed is

```
private function insertContact(UserId:String, UserName:String,ContactName:String, Password:String):void
        {
            stmt.sqlConnection = this.isDbConnected(conn);
            stmt.text = "INSERT INTO TblUsers (UserId, UserName, ContactName ,Password) VALUES('"+UserId+"','"+UserName+"','"+ContactName+"','"+Password+"');"; 
            Alert.show("Contact Has been Saved");
            stmt.execute();
        }  



protected function vtrServices_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Alert.show(SignIn1Result2.lastResult[0].UserName);
                insertContact(SignIn1Result2.lastResult[0].UserId,SignIn1Result2.lastResult[0].UserName,SignIn1Result2.lastResult[0].ContactName,SignIn1Result2.lastResult[0].Password);
                lblWelcome.text = "Welcome"
                lblName.text = SignIn1Result2.lastResult[0].ContactName;
            }
```

Here [0] is my row Index Number

Thanks

Comment: the function is called just like Javascript I was making some mistakes here . i accept it ... Coz i am Noob at ActionScript 3.0 and Flex